# How to convert a HTML/CSS template to haml/sass template?

Tags: css, html, sass, haml

I have a html/css pages done by the front end developer. I have to convert it to haml/ sass to work quickly. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: css is already sass, it's a subset of sass rules, therefore, you can just change the extension and put them in the right place and the files will compile into your sass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

HTML to haml

http://htmltohaml.com/ 

  https://haml2erb.org/

For converting css to sass you may check this tutorial
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/convert-css-to-sass/

http://drilix.com/en/tutorial/convert-your-plain-css-sass-and-compass

If you are thinking of converting sass to css try this app
http://sasstocss.appspot.com/

Comment: the treehouse link isn't a convertor, it's a SASS tutorial aiming to teach SASS from the ground up which is not very quick

Comment: yeah, its not a converter, I just inlcude it. Its better you are aware of preproccesors converter some of them might not give accurate result during convertion so better know first what you are converting